# How should we mitigate against the risk that a leading encryption algorithm does get unexpectedly broken in the near future?

Tags: algorithm, security, encryption, cryptography

I have thought about this question and wondered if the answer below is feasible or just plain ridiculous?

An organisation should always have their data stored on back up servers. Back up servers should exist in case anything happens to the data. To mitigate against the risk that a leading encryption algorithm does get unexpectedly broken in the near future, there should be at least 2 back up servers which are encrypted using a different encryption algorithm so that if a flaw is found in an encryption algorithm the server farm where the current data is being held can be shut down immediately protecting the information. This then leaves two back up server farms where one will then operate as the primary data and the third as the back-up whilst a second back up server form is built.

What suggestions does anyone have?

Comment: Out of curiosity what algorithms would you choose?

Comment: Si as an attacker, with this scheme, I get to choose to attack the worst of the three, the worst maintained, administrated and updated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming; try [IT security](http://security.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are considering data at rest that basically means symmetric key encryption. I suspect that if there is a fundamental break or discovery that there is sufficient similarity between the few top algorithms that it would probably break them all.

Personally I fear a Zombie apocalypse more.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the extra overhead of managing multiple redundant, differently-encrypted backup systems far outweighs the benefit gained. The chances of any modern, mainstream crypto algorithm being "broken" in the near future is incredibly low, and any such break would have such massive effects and implications that your historical corporate records should be pretty far down on the priority list.

For example, breaking RSA would require either the development of fast, efficient quantum computing, or someone finding a new fast solution to the prime-factorization problem. Either of these developments would fundamentally change the computing industry and the function of the internet, above and beyond the loss of RSA.

If you want to future-proof your data, just use a modern, tried-and-tested algorithm with a long key, and keep the key secure. The math strongly suggests that none of them will be broken in the near future.

(As a last note, your proposed system is still weak to any one of the algorithms breaking. If someone has access to all the systems, they can get all the data just by decrypting the weakest one. You would need to distribute your backups among clusters of servers, where each cluster uses a different algorithm, and each cluster has at most 1/(# of clusters) of the backup data. As noted above, this is an insane, impractical overhead, and you would massively increase the potential exposure of your keys, opening you up to a far more likely attack. Not to mention that, even if you do this, some of the data would still be exposed.)

Comment: Any encryption system is vulnerable to employee's abuse. Keeping independent backups isn't so paranoid.

Comment: @F. Stephen Q That doesn't really answer the question. There is concern about EC encryption since it is relatively new compared to factoring.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Keeping independent backups increases the risk because i t increases the name of keys, algorithms, schemes, potential, coding errors and etc.

Comment: @zaph: right. In addition, they need to be managed by different people.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The question wasn't asking about how to protect against any breach, but "How should we mitigate against the risk that a leading encryption algorithm does get unexpectedly broken in the near future?".

Answer (score 1):

Continuing @Zaph's thinking on this, you're making an unfounded assumption that if your encryption scheme were compromised, you would know this at the same time as your attackers. There is no reason to believe that assumption. Assuming the opposite, that the attacker will know about a vulnerability long before you do (which is common), you have doubled your attack surface, hurting your security.

So if a vulnerability is first discovered in some public way, you might win (unless the attackers already stole your data earlier, in which case you lose). If it is first discovered in a secret way by attackers, you lose. If the probabilities of these events are unknown (and I believe they are), you're not doing risk management, you're just gambling. When forced to gamble, always gamble on the simpler solution.